# Let $G(x)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{nx}{1+n^6x^2}$ Prove that $G(x)$ is bounded

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

> Let $G:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$
>
> $$G(x)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{nx}{1+n^6x^2},x\in\mathbb{R}$$ Prove that $G(x)$ is bounded

---

by AGM inequality  :

$$\frac{1+n^6x^2}{2}\ge \sqrt{n^6x^2}$$

$$\iff \frac{1}{2} \ge \frac{\sqrt{n^6x^2}}{1+n^6x^2}$$

$$ \iff \frac{1}{2n^2} \ge \frac{n|x|}{1+n^6x^2}$$

so G(x) is bounded , $M=\frac{1}{2n^2}$

is this correct ? and if i want to prove that it's Pointwise convergence i can say that because $\frac{1}{2n^2}$ is convergence we get also that $\frac{n|x|}{1+n^6x^2}$ is convergence for every $x\in R$?

thanks

Comment: I don't see how the first inequality came from the triangle inequality..

Comment: I think you want $1+n^6x^2\over2$, not $1+{n^6x^2\over2}$, in the opening inequality (which is then the AGM inequality).

Comment: Your first inequality is wrong. Take $n=1$ and $x = 10^{-3}$ for example.

Comment: @BarryCipra yes,that what i meant  my bad , i fixed it

Comment: @J.Doe, your basic reasoning now looks good, but the bound $M$ (on the function $G(x)$) is the infinite *sum* $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over2n^2}={\pi^2\over12}$, not just $1\over2n^2$.

Comment: @BarryCipra that's correct ,thanks

Answer (score 2):

### Easy trick by differentiating:

Let $$g_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+n^6x^2},\implies g'_n(x)=\frac{n-n^7x^2}{(1+n^6x^2)^2}$$

$$g'_n(x)=0 \Longleftrightarrow x= \pm\frac{1}{n^3}$$ and 
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}g_n(x)=0=\lim_{x\to0}g_n(x)$$
Observing that $g_n(x)$ is odd function one easily get that $|g_n|$  attains its maximum at $x= \frac{1}{n^3}$ therefore for all $x$,

$$|g_n(x)|\le |g_n(\frac{1}{n^3})| = \frac{1}{n^2(1+n^3)}$$

And hence,  $$|G(x)|\le\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }|g_n(x)|\le \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^2(1+n^3)} \le \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Answer (score 1):

edit: I was confused by post before edits, so I decided to offer a solution.

Note that if 
$$
y\geq 1
$$
then 
$$
\sqrt{y}\leq y
$$
so, 
$$
1+n^6x^2\geq \sqrt{1+n^6x^2}\geq n^3|x|\\
\implies\frac{n|x|}{1+n^6x^2}\leq\frac{1}{n^2}
$$
so 
$$
|G(x)|=\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{nx}{1+n^6x^2}\right|\leq
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|\frac{nx}{1+n^6x^2}\right|\\
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n|x|}{1+n^6x^2}\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}
$$

As for your second question, we may conclude that the series converges uniformly by the Weirstrass M test.